# Mysterious highlight in emacs

Tags: highlighting, mark

Recently, I change my laptop from old Thinkpad to newer laptop with much larger touchpad. I've found that I frequently touch the sensitive touchpad while I'm using emacs. And with some mysterious combination, very often there will be a highlight appear on the emacs buffer. The highlight is persist. Cannot be removed by navigating cursor or mouse click. It's not emacs selection mark. The only way I can remove it is to close the buffer and reload the file.

This is very annoying. Anybody know what is it, how to remove it, and best if I can prevent it from occur in the first place.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the secondary selection. Clicking and dragging sets the primary selection, and middle click pastes from that selection. Holding alt while clicking and dragging sets the secondary selection, and `M-mouse-2` pastes from it. Very few applications use the secondary selection any more, but it's quite handy when you have two things to copy and paste. See section [12.3.3 Secondary Selection](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Secondary-Selection.html) in the Emacs manual for more information.

There's no command to cancel the secondary selection, but if you left-click with <kbd>Alt</kbd> (`M-mouse-1`), it'll make the secondary selection empty.

Comment: Just alt + click again somewhere, that selection mark will goes away. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please consider adding the info in @Sake's comment to the answer. (Comments can be deleted at any time.)

Answer (score 1):

I use package `disable-mouse`:

```
(package-install "use-package") ; once, if not already installed

(require 'use-package)
(use-package disable-mouse
    :ensure t
    :diminish disable-mouse-global-mode
    :commands global-disable-mouse-mode
    :init (global-disable-mouse-mode))
```